# Why can these arrays not be subtracted from each other?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays

```
a = numpy.array([1, 0])
b = numpy.array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.1],
                 [0.8, 0.5, 0.3]])
```

I want to subtract `b` from `a`.

If I write `a[0] - b[0]` I get `[0.8, 0.6, 0.9]`

If I write `a[1] - b[1]` I get `[-0.8, -0.5, -0.3]`

Subtraction between these arrays is obviously possible, but if I write `a - b`, I get this:

**ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3)**

Why is this not possible?

Comment: Have you read in the basic `numpy` docs about `broadcasting`?  The arrays do have different shapes.

Comment: `(2,) (2,3)` are non-broadcast able  shapes. Reshape `a` to `(2,1)` and it should work. Just add `a = numpy.reshape(a, (2,1))`

Comment: You could do `(a - b.T).T`. More compact than the answer above, but I would use the answer above as it's a bit clearer IMO.